# Create table with 15 minutes interval on date time in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, nstimeinterval

I am trying to create a table in Snowflake with 15 mins interval. I have tried with generator, but that's not give in the 15 minutes interval. Are there any function which I can use to generate and build this table for couple of years worth data.

Such as

| Date | Hour |
| --- | --- |
| 202-03-29 | 02:00 AM |
| 202-03-29 | 02:15 AM |
| 202-03-29 | 02:30 AM |
| 202-03-29 | 02:45 AM |
| 202-03-29 | 03:00 AM |
| 202-03-29 | 03:15 AM |
| ......... | ........ |
| ......... | ........ |

Thanks

Comment: Can timstampadd be used and then iterated over to get desired rows.  select timestampadd(min,45,current_timestamp());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following as time generator with 15min interval and then use other date time functions as needed to extract date part or time part in separate columns.

```
with CTE as
(select timestampadd(min,seq4()*15 ,date_trunc(hour, current_timestamp())) as time_count 
from table(generator(rowcount=>4*24)))
select time_count from cte;
+-------------------------------+
| TIME_COUNT                    |
|-------------------------------|
| 2022-03-29 14:00:00.000 -0700 |
| 2022-03-29 14:15:00.000 -0700 |
| 2022-03-29 14:30:00.000 -0700 |
| 2022-03-29 14:45:00.000 -0700 |
| 2022-03-29 15:00:00.000 -0700 |
| 2022-03-29 15:15:00.000 -0700 |
.
.
.
....truncated output
| 2022-03-30 13:15:00.000 -0700 |
| 2022-03-30 13:30:00.000 -0700 |
| 2022-03-30 13:45:00.000 -0700 |
+-------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many answers to this question [h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71666252/generate-series-equivalent-in-snowflake/71666318#71666318) [e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71473750/duplicating-a-row-a-certain-number-of-times-and-then-adding-30-mins-to-a-timesta/71475320#71475320) [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71387244/fill-in-missing-dates-across-multiple-partitions-snowflake/71390294#71390294) [e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71354827/creating-an-amortization-schedule-in-snowflake/71366357#71366357)  already (those 4 are all this month).

But major point to note is you MUST NOT use `SEQx()` as the number generator (you can use it in the ORDER BY, but that is not needed). As noted in the [doc's](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/seq1.html)

> Important
>
> This function uses sequences to produce a unique set of increasing integers, but does not necessarily produce a gap-free sequence. When operating on a large quantity of data, gaps can appear in a sequence. If a fully ordered, gap-free sequence is required, consider using the ROW_NUMBER window function.

```
CREATE TABLE table_of_2_years_date_times AS
SELECT 
    date_time::date as date,
    date_time::time as time
FROM (
    SELECT 
        row_number() over (order by null)-1 as rn
        ,dateadd('minute', 15 * rn, '2022-03-01'::date) as date_time
    from table(generator(rowcount=>4*24*365*2))
)
ORDER BY rn;
```

then selecting the top/bottom:

```
(SELECT * FROM table_of_2_years_date_times ORDER BY date,time LIMIT 5)
UNION ALL 
(SELECT * FROM table_of_2_years_date_times ORDER BY date desc,time desc LIMIT 5)
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

| DATE | TIME |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-03-01 | 00:00:00 |
| 2022-03-01 | 00:15:00 |
| 2022-03-01 | 00:30:00 |
| 2022-03-01 | 00:45:00 |
| 2022-03-01 | 01:00:00 |
| 2024-02-28 | 22:45:00 |
| 2024-02-28 | 23:00:00 |
| 2024-02-28 | 23:15:00 |
| 2024-02-28 | 23:30:00 |
| 2024-02-28 | 23:45:00 |